# how to detect collision to viewport sides in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a ball(a simple circle) in my view port and I want to know if the ball is colliding to the sides of view port or not?

how can I do that?

I've tried to limit it with some values, but it makes it special and the circle should start from a certain place. I want to have it even if it starts from random coordinates.

This is what I have now:

```
if(vertices[i].first < 1.80f && vertices[i].second <0.9f && left == true
 && !up && !right && !down && !exception){
    c = 'u';
    }

    else if (vertices[i].first < 1.80f && up==true && !right && !down &&
 !left && !exception) {
    c = 'r';
    }

    else if (vertices[i].first > -1.80f && vertices[i].second > -0.9f &&
 right == true && !up && !down && !left && !exception){
    c = 'd';
    }
    else if (vertices[i].first > -1.80f && down == true && !up && !right
 && !left && !exception) {
    c = 'l';
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us some code?

Comment: I added the code I've tried.